TomCat v6 server runtime environment cannot be found in MyEclipse
I'm using MyEclipse (version: 2023.1.2), it does not include the TomCat v6 server (or any server before Tomcat 7) and I can't find the place to download it. I can use *search * to find TomCat6, but it doesn't appear when setting the run configuration.
[window -> preference -> server -> add] (https://i.sstatic.net/KP7yDfGy.png)
[window -> preference -> server -> search] (https://i.sstatic.net/it74vUnj.png)
[.jsp run configuration] (https://i.sstatic.net/4hsbnSpL.png)
How can I fix this?
.jsp->run as-> run configurations -> myeclipse server (new configuration) -> server. It doesn't have Tomcat6 server option

Tomcat 6.0.x , EOL Date: 2016-12-31. you can download it from https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.53/bin/

Tomcat 6 will report an error when using JDK 17 and cannot start. It can be used with JDK 8.

I did use jdk1.8 but the tomcat6 server did not show up in Myeclipse

Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (free) - Eclipse IDE 2022-03 R Packages,   server -> add , support  Apache Tomcat 3.2 +. But  Eclipse IDE 2023-03 R Packages ,  server -> add , support  Apache Tomcat 7+ (No Tomcat 6).  (You can download from here : https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2022-03/r )

Maybe you can check to see if there is a 2022 version of MyEclipse (if you must use MyEclipse with Tomcat 6).

Thx. I installed the 2020 version again. This time it showed the Tomcat6 in the Window->preference->... .
However, I still couldn't find the Tomcat6 option when clicking .jsp->run as-> run configurations -> myeclipse server (new configuration) -> server
